# ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build]: exit code: 1

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm

I'm trying to dockerize my MEAN stack application.
(I'm new to Docker and just learnt it 2 days ago).

After doing `docker compose up`, I get this error:

```
#22 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build]: exit code: 1
------
 > [travelinked-angular client_build 7/7] RUN npm run build:
#22 17.72     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:254:3
#22 17.72     at context.callback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
#22 17.72     at Object.loader (/usr/src/app/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:182:3) {
#22 17.72   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
#22 17.72   library: 'digital envelope routines',
#22 17.72   reason: 'unsupported',
#22 17.72   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
#22 17.72 }
#22 17.72
#22 17.72 Node.js v19.6.0
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build]: exit code: 1
```

I have no idea what is causing this error,  as I don't use `LoaderRunner` or `css-loader`

For my frontend I have this Dockerfile

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:latest AS client_build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm i npm@latest -g

RUN npm install 

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# Stage 2
FROM nginx:latest

COPY --from=client_build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

My backend's Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And this is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.8

services:
  angular:
    hostname: localhost
    build: city-tours-frontend
    ports:
      - 8181:80
  express: 
    build: city-tours-backend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - database

  database:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Do you have any ideas?

Here is a part of the error

```
14 17.08 Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
#14 17.08     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
#14 17.08     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
#14 17.08     at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:144:18)
#14 17.08     at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:46:50)
#14 17.08     at RawSource.updateHash (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/RawSource.js:64:8)
#14 17.08     at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:839:17)
#14 17.08     at handleParseResult (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:904:10)
#14 17.08     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:995:4
#14 17.08     at processResult (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:718:11)
#14 17.08     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:778:5
#14 17.08     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:406:3
#14 17.08     at iterateNormalLoaders (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:10)
#14 17.08     at iterateNormalLoaders (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:239:10)
#14 17.08     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:254:3
#14 17.08     at runSyncOrAsync (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:143:11)
#14 17.08     at iterateNormalLoaders (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:250:2)
#14 17.14 node:internal/crypto/hash:71
#14 17.14   this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
#14 17.14                   ^
#14 17.14
#14 17.14 Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
#14 17.14     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
#14 17.14     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
#14 17.14     at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:144:18)
#14 17.14     at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:46:50)
#14 17.14     at RawSource.updateHash (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/RawSource.js:64:8)
#14 17.14     at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:839:17)
#14 17.14     at handleParseResult (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:904:10)
#14 17.14     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:995:4
#14 17.14     at processResult (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:718:11)
#14 17.14     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:778:5
#14 17.14     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:406:3
#14 17.14     at iterateNormalLoaders (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:10)
#14 17.14     at iterateNormalLoaders (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:239:10)
#14 17.14     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:254:3
#14 17.14     at context.callback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
#14 17.14     at Object.loader (/usr/src/app/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:182:3) {
#14 17.14   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
#14 17.14   library: 'digital envelope routines',
#14 17.14   reason: 'unsupported',
#14 17.14   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a problem with your node version. Try a lower version like `node:14`.